# Implement MySQL Transaction to generate primary key and hold till PHP form-data is submitted

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I've been implementing following function in MySQL to generate ID just after form-data submitted in PHP.

```
FUNCTION `getActivityID`() RETURNS bigint(16)
NO SQL
BEGIN 
DECLARE qid integer;
  SELECT max(id)+1 into qid from wi_activity;
 IF(qid IS NULL) THEN
    SET qid=1;
END IF;
 RETURN convert(concat(6,DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d%m%Y'),lpad(qid,7,'0')), unsigned integer);
```

In above function, **id** is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, the return id is `PRIMARY KEY`.
Every table have at least `ID` and `PRIMARY KEY` (thus generated from function).
for data submission, ajax is used. On slow internet the users happen to click submit button multiple times causing duplicate data.

How can the ID be generated whenever the Form is ready for data input? It requires to lock that `ID` till the data is submitted.

Comment: I need more information about your code, simple answer is you can disable submit button when submit form

Comment: Disabling the submit button is for client-side only. I've used PFBC form builder. I need the server-side solution in which if any logged in user request for new form-data submission then the form-data must contain and hold PRIMARY KEY till the submission. And this PRIMARY KEY must be locked for use by other user.

Comment: you can use a table for requests and another for complete submitted forms, in this way your have always your primary table clean.

Comment: Will not that create redundant table structure and hence break the database characteristics?

Comment: your requests table can have only two fields, id and request date.

Comment: I think that might work. Let me use and will let you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.one`, that will make the button click only once, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

Or more better on  `click` just set a click enable flag = true, and check always against the flag, if true don't hit `ajax`.On request complete or failure you can again set the flag to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

After research I found the answer with `SESSION` variable. While PHP delivering the form, set the random token in the session and pass the token to form as `hidden` `input` as:

```
$random = substr( md5(rand()), 0, 7); //something like this
$_SESSION['form_token']=$random;
```

pass this token as:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
```

The data is inserted if only the `FORM` token and `SESSION` token are same. After insert the `SESSION` token is deleted.